# After driving for a bit the car splutters when I hit the gas until I hit harder then it stops, plus other issues

Tags: stall, chrysler, sebring

After driving for a bit my car bogs down or splutters when accelerating until I hit the gas harder, then the spluttering decreases or stops.

Sometimes the engine dies completely, and when spluttering it has trouble getting over 55-60mph even with the pedal almost to the floor.

Car is 07 Chrysler Sebring I believe v6 but may be 4cyl.

I just changed fuel pump a few months ago, at the time the fuel pump would get hot and cause car to die and have to sit until pump cooled down before being able to start again. When I bought the car, the dealership said they had changed the fuel pump but when I changed it I saw there was no way they did.

The clip on the hose that connects to the fuel pump is broken so I had to rig something up to hold the hose on the pump. In the beginning it kept disconnecting and spraying fuel everywhere. It hasn't done that in months but after getting that to stop it started with the current issue soon after, within a month.

Can someone tell me where to start - what to fix first, or a guaranteed way to figure out exactly what it is. I fix things myself, don't take to a mechanic unless its major, but I can fix most things myself. Just not great at figuring out what is broken, I have a friend or tell me what's broken and then I fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you got an OBD-II scanner you can hook up to see if any fault codes are stored or pending? If not, time to buy one. Try to get one that shows the live data and have a look at this data, or even better save it and post it if you can.

Comment: I forgot it is showing the misfire code.

Comment: How is it misfiring? Dead misfire or wet misfire? A wet misfire, one where the gasoline reaches the missing cylinder but doesn't light up for some reason, usually makes the exhaust smell either of raw gasoline or rotten eggs.

Answer (score 1):

Change the fuel filter, you don't mention that at all and it could easily be a cause of the fuel pump overheating.

The fuel filter could also restrict the delivery to the engine causing the fuel starvation.

Comment: I'll check fuel filter, but it is also sending misfire code